# How to call an Oracle function from Hibernate with a return parameter?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

My question is very much like [Getting the return value of a PL/SQL function via Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068974/getting-the-return-value-of-a-pl-sql-function-via-hibernate)

I have a function which does some modifications internally and it returns a value.

The original idea was to do something like this:

```
protected Integer checkXXX(Long id, Long transId)
        throws Exception {
    final String sql = "SELECT MYSCHEMA.MYFUNC(" + id + ", "
            + transId + ") FROM DUAL";
    final BigDecimal nr = (BigDecimal) this.getHibernateTemplate()
            .getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql)
            .uniqueResult();
    return nr.intValue();
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with Oracle. What is the recommended way to do something like this?

Is there a way to extract declared variables from within my statement?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Hibernate Session provides a [`doWork()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.Work)) method that gives you direct access to [`java.sql.Connection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html). You can then create and use [`java.sql.CallableStatement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) to execute your function:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
  public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call MYSCHEMA.MYFUNC(?,?) }");
    call.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER ); // or whatever it is
    call.setLong(2, id);
    call.setLong(3, transId);
    call.execute();
    int result = call.getInt(1); // propagate this back to enclosing class
  }
});
```

Comment: would you mind to provide an example? I'm a bit lost how to get the result from the function. Do I need to use a out parameter?

Comment: I've provided an example above. Depending on your function / stored procedure you may need to use the other invocation form within `prepareCall()` instead - CallableStatement documentation describes both.

Comment: @ChssPly76: I never knew of `doWork(..)` much better than Hibernate's `@NamedNativeQuery` which requires the sproc/function to return a refcursor as the first parameter (the out parameter).

Comment: @ChssPly76, as I noted below, I didn't copy your answer; I just wrote it at the same time.  My post doesn't deserve a down vote.

Answer (score 13):

You have the following options:

1. With a `@NamedNativeQuery`:

   ```
    @org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "fn_my_func",
        query = "{ ? = call MYSCHEMA.MYFUNC(?, ?) }",
        callable = true,
        resultClass = Integer.class
    )

    Integer result = (Integer) entityManager.createNamedQuery("fn_my_func")
        .setParameter(1, 1)
        .setParameter(2, 1)
        .getSingleResult();
   ```
2. With JDBC API:

   ```
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );

    final AtomicReference<Integer> result = 
        new AtomicReference<>();

    session.doWork( connection -> {
        try (CallableStatement function = connection
                .prepareCall(
                    "{ ? = call MYSCHEMA.MYFUNC(?, ?) }"
                )
            ) {
            function.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER );
            function.setInt( 2, 1 );
            function.setInt( 3, 1 );
            function.execute();
            result.set( function.getInt( 1 ) );
        }
    } );
   ```
3. With a native Oracle query:

   ```
    Integer result = (Integer) entityManager.createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT MYSCHEMA.MYFUNC(:postId, :transId) FROM DUAL")
        .setParameter("postId", 1)
        .setParameter("transId", 1)
        .getSingleResult();
   ```

Comment: When I try the first option, it results with the following exception. Just FYI: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Integer

Comment: You can fork my book, High-Performance Java Persistence, GitHub Repository and [run the test yourself](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/8a2447eddda1b03371197db75c1ddecd32a8654e/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/sp/OracleStoredProcedureTest.java#L209). I've just run it with Hibernate 5.2.11 and it works like a charm.

Comment: @VladMihalcea there is no "resultClass=Integer.class" in your test on GitHub

Comment: @Alex This answer is for the OP question while my GitHub repository is for different examples and use cases.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you do need to use an out parameter.  If you use the doWork() method, you'd do something like this:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
   public void execute(Connection conn) {
      CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("? = call <some function name>(?)");
      stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
      stmt.setInt(2, <some value>);
      stmt.execute();
      Integer outputValue = stmt.getInt(1);
      // And then you'd do something with this outputValue
   }
});
```

Comment: @ChssPly76, I wrote it at the same time as you, and after I posted it, yours was already there.  Nor is it an exact copy, although of course it is quite similar, since the problem is pretty simple to begin with.  It would be nice if you removed your down vote.

Comment: The commonly accepted etiquette on SO is to delete your answer if you see that there's another one just like it already unless they both were literally written at the same time. In this case there's a 16 minute difference between mine and yours. If you delete it now, rep lost due to down-vote will be restored to your account during the next rep recalc (they're usually done every 6 to 8 weeks). Down-vote can not be rescinded (it's too old) unless your answer is edited.

Comment: Oh.  Is it also commonly accepted etiquette to down-vote someone in those cases?

Answer (score 6):

*Alternative code :)*

*if you want to direct result you can use below code*

```
 int result = session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Integer>() {
  @Override
   public Integer  execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call MYSCHEMA.MYFUNC(?,?) }");
    call.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER ); // or whatever it is
    call.setLong(2, id);
    call.setLong(3, transId);
    call.execute();
    return call.getInt(1); // propagate this back to enclosing class
  }
});
```

http://keyurj.blogspot.com.tr/2012/12/dowork-in-hibernate.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void getThroHibConnTest() throws Exception {
    logger.debug("UsersActiion.getThroHibConnTest() | BEG ");
    Transaction tx = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        conn = session.connection();

        System.out.println("Connection = "+conn);
        if (cs == null)
        {
            cs = 
                conn.prepareCall("{ ?=call P_TEST.FN_GETSUM(?,?) }");
        }
        cs.clearParameters();
        cs.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.INTEGER);
        cs.setInt(2,1);
        cs.setInt(3,2);
        cs.execute();
        int retInt=cs.getInt(1);
        tx.commit();            
    }catch (Exception ex) {  
        logger.error("UsersActiion.getThroHibConnTest() | ERROR | " , ex);  
        if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
            try {
                // Second try catch as the rollback could fail as well
                tx.rollback();
            } catch (HibernateException e1) {
                logger.debug("Error rolling back transaction");
            }
            // throw again the first exception
            throw ex;
        }
    }finally{
        try {
            if (cs != null) {
                cs.close();
                cs = null;
            }
            if(conn!=null)conn.close();

        } catch (Exception ex){;}
    }
    logger.debug("UsersActiion.getThroHibConnTest() | END ");
}
```

Comment: the `connection()` method is deprecated in `Hibernate 3.3.2GA+`

Comment: Even `connection()` is deprecated. In those versions this is the way you can access.