# Persisting to SQL Server 2008 using stored procedures, JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, orm, jpa

We are implementing a web page to maintain an organisational structure. The structure is stored in SQL Server 2008 and uses the new HierarchyID data type. Because we have had problems getting JPA and Hibernate to play with this new data type we have decided to use views and stored procedures to abstract away this data type. So we want to use a stored procedure to persist our entities but how you do this with JPA is unclear.

Firstly, are we taking the correct approach and secondly, is it possible to use stored procedures to persist entities annotated with JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have settled on an approach where we use native queries to call stored procedures whenever we need to handle the hierarchy ID data type. This has allowed us to avoid having any proprietary SQL whilst still gaining the benefit of the new data type.

Our understanding, and initial findings, is that the hierarchy ID allows us to aggregate data across a tree structure simply by requesting all descendants of a given node.

For example to get a count of all orders across a 'n' depth structure of regions, offices, stores and departments could use something like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(Orders) FROM Orders WHERE NodeOrderedAt.IsDescendantOf(@Node)
```

@ChssPly76 Thanks for the references to the two models. I will be reading those later :)

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, are we taking the correct approach [...]

Well, it depends. If you don't mind being tied to you database engine then I guess it's not totally wrong to want to benefit from proprietary features like `HierarchyID`. But you don't **have to** use new features...

> secondly, is it possible to use stored procedures to persist entities annotated with JPA?

To my knowledge, **no**. You can call stored procedure using "native queries" (see [`@NamedNativeQuery`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html) and/or [`EntityManager#createNativeQuery()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29)) but you can't use them to persist entities, at least not with JPA. If you don't mind using Hibernate extensions, have a look at `@SQLInsert(callable=true, ...)` (see chapter [2.4.11. Custom SQL for CRUD operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-customsql) of Hibernate Annotations documentation).

---

Personally, I find it very cumbersome to create views, stored procedures and to deal with JPA extensions just to use `HierarchyID`. New features are cool... when they do simplify things, not when they add more complexity which **is** the case here. In other words, because using `HierarchyID` doesn't really solve anything, I think I'd rather stick with a classic `parent_id` column (and this will make the process of changing the database engine smoother even if this is a very unlikely event).

Comment: Big +1 on all of the above; and it's not just insert / update - **any** query dealing with HierarchyID would have to be written as SQL. Seems like more trouble than it's worth. As a small aside - `parent_id` is not the way to map hierarchies :-)

Comment: @ChssPly76 Big thanks :) For my culture, what am I missing about parent/child hierarchies? I'm doubting now but couldn't find an answer in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html. Let me know so that I can fix that part.

Comment: Oh, it's not hibernate-specific. Mapping hierarchies via `parentId` is called 'adjacency list model`. It has its uses in some special circumstances but overall is rather inefficient. 'Nested set model' is arguably a much better approach although somewhat more complex and less performant on "move" operations. You can google either one for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use what @Pascal suggested or you can also use

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery(
     callable=true,
     name="queryname",
     readOnly=true,
     query="call sproc_name(?,:param)",
     resultSetMapping="your_result_mapping"
)
```

see [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/) for full list of options

The only problem with this approach is that the out parameter (if you need one) must be first and must output a refcursor.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703351/how-to-call-a-oracle-function-from-hibernate-with-return-parameter) (it refers to functions but can be modified for sprocs). These examples are based on Oracle but the call string is easily modified for MSSQl.

I don't know much of HierarchyId is it possible to represent as a Hibernate UserType or any of the types?

Comment: I mentioned native query but... this doesn't answer the *is it possible to use stored procedures to **persist** entities annotated with JPA* part.