# How to get Clob data from native query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have tried this:

```
List resultList = session.createSQLQuery("select pack.FuncName ClobData from dual").list()
```

whereis `FuncName` it is the name of function that returns clob data. But in `resultList` I see some proxy object (for example `$Proxy189`). I believe... It is something simple and I don't want ising reflection to get my data.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703351/how-to-call-a-oracle-function-from-hibernate-with-return-parameter helps me. But as I see it this is not a good practice use native calling. Because we are loosing advantages of Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, launching SQL querys directly is not a good idea (by default) using an ORM.

Probably one of the solutions that could fit better in your case will be mapping the CLOB data returned by your `FuncName` to a new non-managed entity (if it's the case). You can create a new entity that fit your requirements and get the data. You can read about it [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e17636) for example.

Of course other solution can be, launch the function that prepares/buils the clob data, save it (for example in a temporary table structure) and then loading it using the @Lob annotation. Check the reference about [Property mapping with annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-property)

Answer (score 1):

I found this solved a similar problem for me without requiring Proxies or custom converters:

```
createSQLQuery("...").addScalar("clob_field", StandardBasicTypes.MATERIALIZED_CLOB);
```