# How to propagate a value back to the enclosing class in Java?

Tags: java

I was looking at this example [Oracle function from Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703351/how-to-call-a-oracle-function-from-hibernate-with-return-parameter). It tells in the solution that:

```
int result = call.getInt(1); // propagate this back to enclosing class
```

Can anyone point me to how this can be done?

Comment: Why not simply pass it to a class field in the enclosing class?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of returning a String instead of an int and propagate this back to enclosing class

```
String results = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().doReturningWork(
    new ReturningWork<String>() {
        public String execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call emb_copy_tool_fc(?,?,?) }");
            call.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.VARCHAR ); // or whatever it is
            call.setString(2, t_order_headers_id);
            call.setString(3, t_new_order_headers_id);
            call.setString(4, p_by);
            call.execute();
            String result = call.getString(1); // propagate this back to enclosing class
            return result;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

This is talking about output parameters of Stored procedure. The link you shown, is actually calling a Stored procedure and getting the output parameter from the PrepareCall, after its been executed successfully.

For this, you need to understand how Output parameters work in SPs.