# Calling Oracle Package from Grails

Tags: oracle, grails, stored-procedures, groovy

Is there a way to call a Function / Procedure within an Oracle Package?
I am able to call a stored procedure like this :

> sql.call 'call myproc(param1,param2)'

and i when i tried to apply the same thing to a package :

> sql.call 'call mypackage.myfunction(param1,param2)'

i had the error : ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name

Any help?

Thanks !

Comment: Check out http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features under the "Stored procedure support" section. Also look at the api http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#call(groovy.lang.GString)

Comment: The first link is where i've got my example. There is nothing related to packages. My guess is that i'll have to do it directly through Hibernate [eg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703351/how-to-call-a-oracle-function-from-hibernate-with-return-parameter) @JacobASeverson

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax:

```
sql.call '{call mypackage.myproc(?,?)}', [p1, p2]
```

and if it is a function:

```
sql.call '{? = call mypackage. myfunction(?,?)}', [result, p1, p2]
```

Comment: `{call mypackage.myproc(?,?)}, [param1,param2]` will output the same error

Comment: check if the user you are connected to the DB has permissions granted to execute the procedure in that package

Comment: try to add the schema name prior to package: '{call schema_name.mypackage.myproc(?,?)}'

Comment: it's not related to the schema because i am able to run it throught java (not groovy) `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:port/xxx";String user = "username";String password = "passwd";Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password); CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{call mypkg.myproc(param1,param2)}");
call.executeQuery();`