# Receive bulk collect oracle in java using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Good aftenoon

I am working in java and I need to work with JDBC (I don't know if another way is recommended) to retrieve a Bulk Collect that is inside a function in an Oracle DB, the function in question has the following definition:

```
  FUNCTION obtenerinfoctaserial(p_xesn IN ces_cuenta_serial.xesn%TYPE)
    RETURN ct_cuenta_serial IS
    lv_retorno ct_cuenta_serial;
  BEGIN
    SELECT t_cuenta_serial(ccuenta,
                           xesn,
                           id_plataforma,
                           finclusion,
                           id_modelo,
                           id_marca) BULK COLLECT
      INTO lv_retorno
      FROM ces_cuenta_serial a
     WHERE a.xesn = p_xesn;

    RETURN(lv_retorno);
  END obtenerinfoctaserial;
```

I think the idea is to retrieve it through the type Oracle.Types.ARRAY and after that it is stored in an array of string STRING[], but I have the doubt of how to make the call code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call oracle function from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902849/how-to-call-oracle-function-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

A PIPELINED function or a function returning an array of OBJECT (or a Polymorphic Table Function) is seen as returning the rows of a table:
In SQL, you would write:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_function(?)) ;
```

or in recent ORACLE versions:

```
SELECT * FROM my_function(?) ;
```

so you should get the result as any result set from a "standard" select.

You should play with Oracle.Types.ARRAY only for IN or OUT parameters of a function/procedure.