# How to call oracle function in oracle store procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to call a oracle function inside a procedure, oracle function returns the sys_refcursor, I want to iterate this cursor inside procedure and return the list from the procedure so that i can get the list using java code. i have tried accessing the function using java, but could not get the result. 
my oracle function look like this.

```
   create or replace function myfun(pi_id_pout_order in port_out_order.id_pout_order % type)
   return sys_refcursor is
   lc_cursor sys_refcursor;
begin

   open lc_cursor for
      select id_pout_order
            ,id_lec_user
            ,id_pout_lec
            ,id_service_rec
            ,pout_tn
            ,id_iptn
            ,pout_lec_ocn
            ,pout_lec_spid
            ,pout_ali_code
            ,lec_contact_fname
            ,lec_contact_lname
            ,lec_contact_tn
            ,lec_contact_email
            ,dl_lec_ocn
            ,cust_acct
            ,cust_f_name
            ,cust_l_name
            ,svc_addr_str
            ,svc_addr_num
            ,svc_addr_city
            ,svc_addr_state
            ,svc_addr_zip
            ,pout_loa_date
            ,pout_ddd
            ,pout_foc
            ,e_mail_sent_date
            ,v_mail_sent_date
            ,id_pout_status
            ,customer_type
            ,authorization_name
            ,id_master_pout_order
        from port_out_order
       where id_pout_order = pi_id_pout_order
         and id_pout_status < 95;

   return lc_cursor;
end;
```

How do i do this?

Comment: Why not just call the function directly from Java and then iterate over the returned result set there rather than trying to make a procedure to convert it to a list? Also, Oracle does not have a "list" data structure - did you mean to return it as a collection or a `VARRAY` or a delimited string or something else?

Comment: @MT0 collection will do the job, i just need the value, i have tried calling the function and try to get the value, struggled for a week, could not do it, see the link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221511/how-to-call-oracle-function-which-return-sys-refcursor-using-java-hibernate`

Comment: Added an answer to that question - hopefully it makes this question irrelevant.